# How to use a microcontroller that has no RAM?

Tags: memory, embedded, microcontroller, ram

Some microcontrollers ([such as the ATtiny12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATtiny_microcontroller_comparison_chart)) have no SRAM at all. How is it even possible to get them to do anything useful? And why would anyone make such a limited device?

The only way I can think of to program a chip with no RAM is using some kind of primitive state machine, where the current value of the program counter essentially defines the state. For example:

```
Do
  Wait for button press
  Illuminate the LED
  Wait for button release
  Extinguish the LED
Loop
```

I'm not trying to solve a specific problem, I'm just curious. Can anything more complicated be achieved without memory? I've tried googling, with no useful results.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You may not have SRAM, but it does have registers--and a fair amount of them.  With careful use, you can use them like variables and use the EEPROM for persisting some data.  All together, you can do quite a bit. :-)

Comment: Hey @JohnSzakmeister, please make it an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: Good point. I see in the datasheet it says "32 general-purpose working registers". I guess that's pretty much the same as RAM, and changes the game entirely. Make an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: You should also forget about using C for such limited MCUs. I did some fooling around in C with Freescale RS08, which is another extremely limited one with no stack. Wasn't pretty. No idea why they even bothered porting a C compiler to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may not have SRAM, but it does have registers--and a fair amount of them. With careful use, you can use them like variables and use the EEPROM for persisting some data. All together, you can do quite a bit.